# Setting the value of a variable in one method and print in the other

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm trying to set the value of a variable in one method and print it in another but the printing method doesn't recognize what the setting method did.

```
public class Example{

    private int number;

    public Example(){
    }


    public void setValue(){
       number = 5;
    }

    public void printValue(){
        System.out.print(number);
    }

}

public class TestExample{

   public static void main(String[] args){
      Example objectExample = new Example();
      objectExample.printValue();
   }
}
```

The output will be equals 0

Comment: please, add the code where you are invoke methods of class 'example'

Comment: This piece of code looks clean. Maybe you are trying to print it directly `System.out.print(example1.setValue())` which won't work. Because you don't have `return` on that method, even though you have defined it.

Comment: I'm mainly confused about why the output will not be 5 if I put the print statement is in another method. If I put the print statement in setValue, the output will be 5.

Comment: Before printing the value you have to invoke the setter on the same object. Just by having a setter won't assign that 5 on to the variable number. You have do it like the answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

You must first invoke your setter before using printValue().

```
Example objectExample = new Example();
objectExample.setValue();
objectExample.printValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the value, currently the Integer number has a value of null, you need to assign a value to it before executing the printValue method.

````java
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Example objectExample = new Example();
      objectExample.setValue();
      objectExample.printValue();
 ```  }
````